# I do not want to redirect to other form onclick but display components within the same form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am doing my college project onclick event I do not want to open a new form but show the component in the same form by disabling the components of the previous option.

For instance, if I click on ADD button, it will open a new form with details to be added to save.

But, I want to show all those components of ADD form in the same form where click event occurs.

My design is something like, all options will be in left hand side and the result / form with component has to be displayed in the right hand side without opening a new form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Panel Control**

Add multiple panels one over the other, like a stack.

Either use:

- `panel1.Visible=false ; panel2.Visible=true` on button click
- `panel1.Enabled=false ; panel2.Enabled=true` on button click

according to your design

Refer this video: **[link‎](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDOXzz_0gYE%E2%80%8E)**

Answer (score 2):

Use **Panels**.

The Panel Control is a container control to host a group of similar child controls. One of the major uses I have found for a Panel Control is when you need to show and hide a group of controls. Instead of show and hide individual controls, you can simply hide and show a single Panel and all child controls.

[panel-in-C-Sharp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/panel-in-C-Sharp/)

[working-multiple-panels-c-sharp](http://dotnetdots.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/working-multiple-panels-c-sharp/)